# Text not appending in text file

Tags: python, text, append

The text under the function existing_bal() is not appending in the text file that gets created. It was working sometime back but it just stopped working and I have no clue why. It is not because of the text file existing cause I deleted it before I ran the code. It does generate a new file but it doesn't append the text

```
def existing_bal():
  global file_name
  file_name = user_name +'_transactionhistory.txt'
  try:
    f = open(file_name,'r')
  except:
    f = open(file_name,'w+')
    to_append = ("Username"+'\t'+user_name+'\t'+'Original_Balance' +'\t'+'0'+'\n')
    f.write(to_append)
  check_bal()

def check_bal():
  lines_list = open(file_name).read().split( )
  print(lines_list)
  bank_func()
```

Comment: Nothing will be written to the file if it exists

Comment: Try closing the file or, even better, use a Work Manager. Also, what is the purpose of opening in readonly mode?

Comment: that was cause read only doesnt create a new file and if it doesnt previously exists, it will give an error

Comment: you should be using `os.path.exists()` for that purpose

Comment: In that case just open it in 'a+' mode and don't forget to close it after appending